# When using Sinon.js to create mocks, what does mock.restore() actually do?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I've started using Sinon.js to mock a MongoDB library in a Mocha test suite. I'm confused as to why `mock.restore()` in my `afterEach` blocks do not actually clear out the mocks & assertions I've set up in other tests. Example:

```
mockedMongo.expects('updateCustomer').once();
mockedMongo.restore();
mockedMongo.expects('updateCustomer').never();
mockedMongo.verify(); // error here
```

The last line will throw an `Expected updateCustomer([...]) once (never called)` ExpectationError. In [the documentation](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.5/mocks/) it says that `mock.restore()` "Restores all mocked methods". I'm trying to figure out what that actually means, since it doesn't clear out my previous expectation, even when it seems that I've overwritten the mock on that method with something else. Thoughts?

Comment: The restore methods do not affect your assertions, this is for restoring the mock or stub method itself, for example, if you want to stub a method in your mockedMongo, "sinon.stub(mockedMongo, "find", stubFindFunction)". This will change the behavior of how original "find" function works for a specific test suite, to make sure its original functionality is restored you call "mock.restore();"
Here are some examples of use cases https://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs "Stub API"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary**

If any methods have been wrapped in a proxy by the mock, `restore()` returns them to their original state.  That's all it does.

**Details**

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/722ac09f23fa5b87fa8e71b5feac5341314281a3/lib/sinon/mock.js#L58-L121) gives the following info:

- calling `expects()` sets up a `proxy` for the method if no `expectations` have been set on it yet, and then adds an `expectation`
- calling `verify()` cycles the expectations on the proxies and verifies each, then calls `restore()`
- `restore()` cycles the proxies and restores the original methods

All `restore()` does is remove any proxies added by `expects()`, it doesn't affect the `expectations` stored by the mock.

So for each line in your example code:

1. create proxy for `updateCustomer` and add `expectation` of `once`
2. restore original `updateCustomer`
3. add `expectation` of `never` to `updateCustomer`
4. cycle the two `expectations` on `updateCustomer` and record that `once` fails, call `restore()`, then report that `once` failed